# Event provider and subscriber right way of using

Tags: vb.net

Three questions:

1. Whether this way of using events is correct?
2. I can't get idea of using WithEvents i saw on some example people are using it can you explain for instance according to my example or when it should be used.
3. Is it possible to not create this case :

   Dim Subscrib1 As New Policeman(carStart)

what i mean is i want to have class which i would not need to create instance for example let's take Policeman class, do i really need to create his instance and pass carStart to it to receive event? For instance let's imagine Policeman class contain method Do and inside Console.writeline("doSomething"). I want this method to be executed when somwhere carStart.Drive was raised.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim carStart As New Driver(122)
        Dim Subscrib1 As New Passenger(carStart)
        Dim Subscrib2 As New PoliceControl(carStart)

        carStart.StartToDrive()
        carStart.CheckCurrentSpeed()

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Class Driver
        Public Delegate Sub DoIt()
        Public Event Drive As DoIt
        Public Event CurrentSpeed()

        Public SpeedDrive As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal speed As Integer)
            Me.SpeedDrive = speed
        End Sub

        Public Sub StartToDrive()
            Console.WriteLine("I am driving")
            RaiseEvent Drive()
        End Sub

        Public Sub CheckCurrentSpeed()
            Console.WriteLine("Current speed is " & SpeedDrive)
            RaiseEvent CurrentSpeed()
        End Sub

    End Class

    Class Passenger
        Sub New(classWithevent As Driver)
            If classWithevent.SpeedDrive = 0 Then
                AddHandler classWithevent.Drive, AddressOf TakePassanger
            Else
                RemoveHandler classWithevent.Drive, AddressOf TakePassanger
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub TakePassanger()
            Console.WriteLine("Taking passenger")
        End Sub
    End Class

    Class PoliceControl
        Sub New(classWithevent As Driver)
            If classWithevent.SpeedDrive > 120 Then
                AddHandler classWithevent.CurrentSpeed, AddressOf PolicemanCheckTheCarSpeed
            Else
                RemoveHandler classWithevent.CurrentSpeed, AddressOf PolicemanCheckTheCarSpeed
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Sub PolicemanCheckTheCarSpeed()
            Console.WriteLine("Stop for control")
        End Sub
    End Class

End Module
```